# Sub or Function not defined

Tags: excel, vba

Being self taught I have not learned everything there is to know about Excel VBA. Hell lets be honest, I know some basics, but not as much as I probably should, so this question although probably a generic basic question, probably should be known by someone who knows VBA, but in the case of I learn what I need to move forward... so I need an explanation.

When do you need to define a Sub or Function?  Why do you need to define a Sub or Function? What is the purpose of defining a Sub or Function?

I only ask, because of this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenOrderReportExport()

    Dim wsJL As Worksheet   'Jobs List
    Dim wsPOT As Worksheet  'PO Tracking
    Dim wsTNO As Worksheet  'Tel-Nexx OOR
    Dim wbBK2 As Workbook   'New Workbook
    Dim wsWS1 As Worksheet  'Sheet1
    Dim wsWS2 As Worksheet  'Sheet2
    Dim wsWS3 As Worksheet  'Sheet3


    Set wsJL = Sheets("Jobs List")      'Jobs List
    Set wsPOT = Sheets("PO Tracking")   'PO Tracking
    Set wsTNO = Sheets("Tel-Nexx OOR")  'Tel-Nexx OOR
    Set wbBK2 = Workbook("Book2")       'New Workbook
    Set wsWS1 = Sheets("Sheet1")        'Sheet1
    Set wsWS2 = Sheets("Sheet2")        'Sheet2
    Set wsWS3 = Sheets("Sheet3")        'Sheet3

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False    ' Prevents screen refreshing.
        CurrentFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
        NewFileType = "Excel Files 2007 (*.xlsx)"
        NewFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="Open Order Log - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".txt", fileFilter:=NewFileType)

End Sub
```

Why does this sub need to be defined? I am putting it as a standard module, and working on setting it up so that once a button is pushed I will be able to move a few pages over to a new workbook, delete the blank ones, and go from there with a save function that you tell it where to save.

I have a long way to go, but I wanted to test out the save function, and go from there, because to me that is going to be the hardest thing.

So without solving my entire conundrum, I would like to know why something like this needs to be defined? And how it needs to be defined... if someone could give an answer it be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you are getting an error that says the Sub or Function is not defined. This type of error means that the call you made to a subroutine or a function is not currently defined in the module - basically it does not exist. My guess on where you are getting the error - at the Application.GetSaveAsFilename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the problem.

The following line of code is incorrect. It does not create a new workbook like you think it does. The function `Workbook` does not exist - when you try to run/compile the VBA editor complains that the function does not exist.

```
Set wbBK2 = Workbook("Book2")       'New Workbook
```

Change it to

```
set wbBK2 = Workbooks.add
```

and it will create a new workbook and save a reference in `wbBK2`. Alternatively you could reference an open workbook by adding an "s" to `Workbook` if you are not trying to make a new one:

```
Set wbBK2 = Workbooks("Book2")       'New Workbook
```

You also will need to dimension these variables as strings eventually:

```
    Dim CurrentFile as String        
    Dim NewFileType as String
    Dim NewFile as String

    CurrentFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    NewFileType = "Excel Files 2007 (*.xlsx)"
    NewFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="Open Order Log - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".txt", fileFilter:=NewFileType)
```

---

Another note, too - when you use

```
Set wsWS1 = Sheets("Sheet1")        'Sheet1
Set wsWS2 = Sheets("Sheet2")        'Sheet2
Set wsWS3 = Sheets("Sheet3")        'Sheet3
```

You probably want to change this to reference the sheets in the other workbook

```
Set wsWS1 = wbBK2.Sheets("Sheet1")        'Sheet1
Set wsWS2 = wbBK2.Sheets("Sheet2")        'Sheet2
Set wsWS3 = wbBK2.Sheets("Sheet3")        'Sheet3
```

as it will be quite helpful to maintain the right references to these sheets, even if you add additional workbooks.

Comment: this is guess work based on the OP - which is vague. You've put some quite a bit of work into answering the question therefore I wouldn't like to mark your answer down.

Comment: @whytheq you realize that I answer the OP's actual issue in the beginning, right?  The problem the OP had was a "sub not defined error." This was definitely being caused by the code     `Set wbBK2 = Workbook("Book2")`

Comment: & THE THREE UNDEFINED NAMES WERE THROWING THE SAME ERROR. All beside the point the OP was vague + I put effort into my answer which the OPer did not say was wrong; therefore -1 was uncalled for. (note that I edited and improved your answer i.e stuck to the general spirit of SO)

Comment: Interesting. I receive "Variable not defined" compile errors trying to run code just using those lines - what version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Your post revolves around the following questions so let me explain them one by one.

**YOUR QUESTIONS**

1. When do you need to define a Sub or Function?
2. Why do you need to define a Sub or Function?
3. What is the purpose of defining a Sub or Function?
4. Why does this sub need to be defined?

VBA Supports two types of procedures: **Sub Procedures** and **Function procedures**.

A **Sub procedure** consists of series of statements and can be executed in a number of ways for example

```
Sub Sample()
    MsgBox "Hello Matt Ridge"
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub Sample()
    Sample1 "Hello Matt Ridge"
End Sub

Sub Sample1(s As String)
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

[image]

A VBA **Function** on the other hand returns a single value or possibly an array. A function can be called from another VBA procedure or used in a worksheet formula. For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret As String

    Ret = GreetUser("Matt Ridge")

    MsgBox Ret
End Sub

Public Function GreetUser(User As String)
    GreetUser = "Hello " & User
End Function
```

The same function can also be called in a worksheet. For example of Cell A1 has `Matt Ridge` and when you type this formula in cell B1

```
=GreetUser(A1)
```

You will get `Hello Matt Ridge` in Cell B1. See the below snapshot.

[image]

Now looking at your code.

When you say

```
    Dim wbBK2 As Workbook
```

Then VBA expects you to set the variable accordingly as enderland mentioned. In your case, VBA is looking for `WORKBOOKS()` which is an inbuilt method. However when VBA sees `WORKBOOK()` which it doesn't recognize, it tries to find the `SUB PROCEDURE` in the module (*hoping that you might have defined it somewhere*) and when it doesn't find it, it pops that error. :)

Hope this answers your questions.

Comment: This is a good answer which gets at the heart of the question's issue. +1

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you areb using OPTION EXPICIT which means all Variables mst be defined.
One way to achive this and make your code nice and readable is to use Colon as line contiuation when you first define and set the object:

Example Below:

```
Option Explicit 

Sub OpenOrderReportExport() 

    Dim wsJL As Worksheet:  Set wsJL = Sheets("Jobs List")      'Jobs List 
    Dim wsPOT As Worksheet: Set wsPOT = Sheets("PO Tracking")   'PO Tracking 
    Dim wsTNO As Worksheet: Set wsTNO = Sheets("Tel-Nexx OOR")  'Tel-Nexx OOR
    Dim wbBK2 As Workbook:  Set wbBK2 = Workbook("Book2")       'New Workbook 
    Dim wsWS1 As Worksheet: Set wsWS1 = wbBK2.Sheets("Sheet1")  'Sheet1 
    Dim wsWS2 As Worksheet: Set wsWS2 = wbBK2.Sheets("Sheet2")  'Sheet2  
    Dim wsWS3 As Worksheet: Set wsWS3 = wbBK2.Sheets("Sheet3")  'Sheet3 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False    ' Prevents screen refreshing. 
    Dim CurrentFile as string: CurrentFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName 
    Dim NewFileType as string: NewFileType = "Excel Files 2007 (*.xlsx)" 
    Dim NewFileType as string: NewFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="Open Order Log - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".txt", fileFilter:=NewFileType) 

End Sub
```